# DeletionPolicy:Snapshot cannot be specified for a cluster instance, use deletion policy on the cluster instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am trying to create RDS cluster and aurora instance using the cloudoformation template below:

```
{
      "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "example setup",

  "Parameters" : {
    "DBInstanceIdentifier" : {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Name for the DB instance."
    },
    "DBUser" : {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Master user"
    },
    "DBPassword" : {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Pass"
    },
    "DBModel" : {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Instance model to be used for the DB."
    }
  },


  "Resources": {
    "RDSCluster": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
      "Properties": {
        "MasterUsername": { "Ref" : "DBUser" },
        "MasterUserPassword": { "Ref" : "DBPassword" },
        "Engine": "aurora",
        "DBClusterParameterGroupName": "default.aurora5.6",
        "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [{"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "DBFromSiteSecurityGroup" , "GroupId" ]}]
      }
    },
    "AuroraInstance": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
      "Properties": {
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": { "Ref" : "DBInstanceIdentifier" },
        "DBParameterGroupName": "default.aurora5.6",
        "Engine": "aurora",
        "DBClusterIdentifier": {
          "Ref": "RDSCluster"
        },
        "PubliclyAccessible": "true",
        "DBInstanceClass": { "Ref" : "DBModel" }
      }
    },

    "DBFromSiteSecurityGroup" : {
       "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
       "Properties" : {
          "GroupDescription" : "Enable MySQL",
          "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
             {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "3306", "ToPort" : "3306", "CidrIp" : "195.171.102.98/32"}
          ]
       }
    },
     "DBFromSiteSecurityGroupIngress1" : {
         "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
         "Properties" : {
             "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "DBFromSiteSecurityGroup" },
             "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
             "ToPort" : "3306",
             "FromPort" : "3306",
             "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "DBFromSiteSecurityGroup" }
         }
     }
  }
}
```

The db_model parameter I am passing is "db.t2.medium". The cluster gets created successfully in the cloudformation console however the AWS::RDS::DBInstance creation fails with the following error

```
"DeletionPolicy:Snapshot cannot be specified for a cluster instance, use deletion policy on the cluster instead."
```

What's more weird that when I try to run the same CF template in say eu london region, it works fine!!! Is there something wrong with the EU ireland region and aurora?

Comment: It seems like a AWS issue. I update our production CFN stack earlier this morning without issues but now its giving me the same error when I'm updating stack - the funny thing is I'm not even updating the Aurora DB instance. Both stacks are in Ireland region.

Comment: so how are supposed to solve the issue? Is there any issue tracker we need to submit to?

Comment: I've run into this same issue as well starting yesterday. There doesn't seem to be a way to define that policy in the cluster though so I agree that this is an AWS error in requirements and have not found a resolution myself yet either.

Comment: I'll also mention that I was trying to deploy this to us-west-2. Haven't found a method to resolve this yet, but have submitted a tech support ticket.

Comment: I'm having the same - despite not specifying a deletion policy in my stack.  Must be a recent change

Comment: I'm also having this issue when trying to delete a stack. The delete process fails and the instances still remain. Any advise on how to successfully delete the stack?

Comment: They are testing the fix currently, will update when support advise problem is resolved globally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From AWS Support

> This is a known issue and has been reported by other customers as well. The service team is currently working on the fix for this but there is no ETA as to when that would be pushed.
>
> The work-around in the meanwhile is to specify a DeletionPolicy inside the DB instance resource definition that is failing to create, with the value of 'Delete'. [1]
>
> An example below:

```
"Resources": { 
    "Database1": { 
        "DeletionPolicy": "Delete", 
        "Properties": {...}, 
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance" 
    } 
}
```

> References:
>   [1] DeletionPolicy - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html#w2ab2c19c23c11c17

Comment: Worked for me too! Been stuck with this for 2 days!

Answer (score 1):

An update from [AWS Support](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=259843):

> When creating an Amazon Aurora DBInstance in a DB Cluster using AWS
>   CloudFormation, CloudFormation applies a default Deletion policy of
>   “Delete”, if a deletion policy is not specified. If a Deletion Policy
>   of “Snapshot” is specified for an Amazon Aurora DBInstance,
>   CloudFormation returns an error, because instances in a DB Cluster
>   cannot be snapshotted individually; Snapshotting must be done at the
>   DB Cluster level.
>
> As part of a recent deployment, we inadvertently changed the default
>   deletion policy for an Amazon Aurora DBInstance to “Snapshot”. This
>   caused our template validation to fail. To remedy this, CloudFormation
>   is reverting the value of default DeletionPolicy for Amazon Aurora
>   DBInstances to “Delete”. This fix will be completed by 21st July,
>   2017. Until this fix is completely rolled out, customers can explicitly override our incorrect defaults by specifying a deletion
>   policy of “Delete” for Amazon Aurora DBInstances.
>
> We have corrected the gap in our testing that led to this situation,
>   and will continue to improve our testing to prevent recurrences. We
>   recognize how critical it is for us to preserve existing behavior for
>   our customers, and apologize for this inconvenience.